# Как сделать активным меню wordpress при выбранной категории woocomerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как к категориям woocommerce (product_cat) применить активное меню, чтобы при определённых категориях подсвечивалось определённое меню.

Есть меню из двух пунктов. Яблоки Груши
У каждого товара своя категория, у яблок (категория1, категория2,категория3) у груш (категория 4, категория5)
как сделать активным(добавить current-menu-item или другой класс) то меню, к которому относится определенная категория.
Если выбрана категории (категория1, категория2,категория3) то меню Яблоки активное а груши соответственно нет.
Если выбрана категория (категория 4, категория5) то активное меню Груши

нашел пример такой (Сделает активным пункт меню с названием Blog, если находимся на странице рубрики с ID = 5. 
Если нужно и для записей этой рубрики, то добавить in_category(5).)

```html
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 2 );

function add_custom_class( $classes = array(), $menu_item = false ) {
    if ( 'Blog' == $item->title && is_category(5) ) {
         $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

нужно использовать is_product_cat ? подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Второй параметр включает в себя id - текущего поста/термина. Нужно проверить сразу является ли этот элемент меню товаров. Затем взять у него категории и, если есть категории, добавить новый класс. Пример:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_custom_class', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_class( $classes, $menu_item ) {    
    if ( is_product_cat() && 'product_cat' === $menu_item->object ) {
        $current_object = get_queried_object();
        $parents = get_terms( [
            'parent'   => $current_object->term_id,
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'fields'  => 'ids'
        ] );

        if ( in_array( $menu_item->object_id, $parents ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }

    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения а можно чуточку подробнее, вот меню Яблоки(apple) id у меню 118 и есть категория товара (Категория1(cat1)) у нее id 86 немного не пойму как проверить является ли этот элемент меню товара ведь элемент является категорией товара. Грубо говоря если я выбрал категорию товара woocommerce (cat1) то меню Главная например чтобы подсвечивалось как активное. Простите если тупые вопросы просто только пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Ты очень сложно объясняешь....можно как-то проще объяснить, что ты хочешь?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при выборе категории товара определенный пункт меню стал активным чтобы подсвечивался (нажал на категорию товара "красные яблоки") и чтобы меню Яблоки было активным.

Comment: 1.Есть два пункта меню (Груши и Яблоки)
2. Есть товары с категориями (категория1,категория2, категория3)
3. Нужно чтобы при выборе категории подсвечивался определенный пункт меню
Пример: Если нажать на категорию товара (категория1) то пункт меню Яблоки становится активным( подсвечивается) появляется класс у него active или current-menu-item, если нажать на (категория3) Тогда пункт меню Груша активным становится

Comment: @Sam Правильно я понимаю, что у вас 2 категории, внутри подкатегории. Вы должны подсвечивать категории верхнего уровня, находясь на страницах категорий нижнего?

Comment: только не путайте обычные категории is_category речь идет о категориях woocommerce там is_product_category. мне нужно находясь на страницах категорий товаров woocommerce (product_category) сделать активным пункт обычного меню wp. Например пункт меню Главная (он должен быть активен, подсвечен) если мы выбрали категорию ТОВАРА не категория WP

Comment: Понял. Сейчас подправлю код, а вы более понятнее отредактируйте ваш вопрос)

Comment: @Sam Пробуйте, поправил код

Comment: А могу ли я сам указать к какому именно меню применить  $classes[] = 'active'; не к родителю, так как повторюсь это НЕ подкатегории меню, это не рубрики (простые категории Wp) это категории Woocommerce

Comment: if ( 'Apple' == $menu_item->title && is_product_category( 'cat1' ) )

Comment: просто при таких условия код не отрабатывает у меня

Comment: is_product_category проверяет что текущая страница это категория товара со слагом cat1

Comment: Да. я бы сюда кусок кода вставил бы не пойму как в комментарии вставлять вставлять

Comment: if ( 'Glavmenu' == $item->title && is_product_category( 'woman' ) ) {
Glavmenu- это название меню в wp котором есть 1 пункт Главная,